# After effects: Blending Mode problem

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to use the blending mode. When I start the project, there is no problem with the blending mode. But after a few days, the blending mode of some of my precomps always changes to "-". After that the effects are deleted and I can't change the state.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: here is an example of how it looks like...]

Answer (score 1):

I think this can happen when you switch on Collapse Transformations (the sun icon [image] ) on your pre-comp.  This changes the order in which After Effects renders things - there's a good example of this here:

https://pixelsandpaths.com/posts/tutorials/using-collapse-transformations-and-continuously-rasterize-in-after-effects-by-school-of-motion/